# How to intercept the default 200 response sent from HttpResponse?

Tags: java, android, androidhttpclient

I need to send a response based on a flag(loginStatus), however, before this, a default 200 response is being sent. How do I intercept the response ?

```
private void handlePost(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) {
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    HttpEntity entity = ((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest)request).getEntity();

   **// Handling the request here ......**

    Handler mainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HttpEntity respEntity = new EntityTemplate(new ContentProducer() {
                public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
                    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outstream, "UTF-8");
                    final InputStream in = getContext().getAssets().open( "home.html" );

                    IOUtils.copy(in, writer);
                    writer.flush();
                }
            });
            response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
            response.setEntity(respEntity);

          **//the loginStatus value is asynchronous so waiting for 5000**

            if(loginStatus){
         **// set status code 201**
                response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_CREATED);
            } else {
         **// set status code 501**
                response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
        }
    };

    mainHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
}
```

Comment: 1) don't write the network layer yourself 2) use a library like retrofit 3) implement an Interceptor

Answer (score 1):

You should use a library to do this, it's better than write the network layer yourself.
You can use OkHttp to manage Http Request and implement an interceptor, see this https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors 
You can write a CustomClass that implements Interceptor interface and override this method

```
@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    Response response = chain.proceed(request);
    if (response.code() = 200) {
        //Do what you want
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "INTERCEPTED:$ " response.toString());
    return response;
}
```